# Binding NSTextField's Enabled property to a BOOL property

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, binding, nstextfield

I am a Mac dev newbie. I have a dialog with some set of controls. The controls needs to be enabled/disabled based on a radio selection. The way I did it is by creating IBOutlet variables for each of these controls and then calling control's SetEnabled() when the radio  selection changes. It all works fine but now there are 8 IBOutlet variables and then 8 statements to set their state. Wondering if there is a *nice* way to do it through binding?

I declared a BOOL property *typeOneEnabled* and set the NSTextField's Enabled binding to File Owner >> typeOneEnabled. Thought it would change the enabled state when the property changes but that does not seem to work. Am I missing something here or its not possible?

```
// in header I have  
BOOL typeOneEnabled;  
@property BOOL typeOneEnabled;

// in mm file  
@synthesize typeOneEnabled

// then to change the property val in a method  
self.typeOneEnabled = someval;
```

I remember putting some code immediately before and after setting the property value but it did not work and I reverted it. Was something related to WithKey:@"typeOnEnabled".

Comment: can you show some code? It should work, but only if all access to the typeOneEnabled variable happens KVO compliant.

Comment: @Volker: I've added some code to the question.

Comment: That looks good in general. Have you also bound the text field value to a property?

Comment: Yes the Value property is bound to some other property to load default values on startup.

Comment: Okay, check that conditionallySetsEditable is not activated in the value binding... if that is it, i would post an answer combining the comments

Comment: Yes it is set. The following properties are set: "Allow editing multiple values selection", "Conditionally Sets Editable" and "Raises for non applicable keys".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `enabled` binding is used for `NSTextField` and related make sure the bound `BOOL` property is always accessed through the KVO accessors by using the setter method or the dot syntax. Also make sure that if the 'NSTextField' value is also bound to a property, that the value binding does disable `Conditionally Sets Editable`. Otherwise this leads to enabling of the control.